# File not read by Java until touched

Tags: files, solaris, java

We had a freak incident on Solaris. Our java program couldn't read a file until we touched the file. It was reading other files just fine, it just seemed to be completely blind to this one particular file. We use standard java FileReader for reading the file. After we touched the file, it was picked up and processed instantaneously. No issues with permissions either. Any idea what caused this?

Comment: creation date may be?

Comment: We don't look at dates when processing files. Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: sorry i mean access time and modification time. The only thing touch does is change access time and modification time. And ofcourse creation of file if its not present. I hope the file was present.

Comment: I don't believe in "freak incidents". Do you know the saying: "if you hear hoofbeats think horses not zebras" ?  :-)

Comment: Yeah.. The file was present.